# Can a TLB hit lead to a page fault?

Tags: operating-systems

$Can$ $a$ $TLB$ $hit$ $lead$ $to$ $a$ $page$ $fault?$

My answer is yes, as say even after a TLB hit if the page in the memory is dirty and it will lead to Page fault. Other case can be that, it is read only and we want to write that page which will eventually lead to page fault.

---

Now wrt this context, let me ask u question that was asked in GATE 2020 exam(India's one of the most prestigious examination to get into $IIT's$ for Masters and PhD). I know this is not a question ans posting site, but for the sake of clearing my doubt I have to, and the concept can be understood well through this question. The questions goes like this-->

> Consider a paging system that uses $1−level$ page table residing in
>   main memory and a TLB for address translation. Each main memory access
>   takes $100 ns$ and TLB lookup takes $20 ns$. Each page transfer
>   to/from the disk takes $5000 ns$. Assume that the TLB hit ratio is
>   $95%$, page fault rate is $10%$. Assume that for $20%$ of the total
>   page faults, a dirty page has to be written back to disk before the
>   required page is read from disk. TLB update time is negligible. The
>   average memory access time in ns (round off to $1$ decimal places) is
>   _______.

There is a lot of fuss going around this question as the answer provided by the exam authority is claiming it to range from $154.5ns$ $to$ $155.5ns$, but many fellow scholars are claiming that it should be $725ns$ as there can still be page faults if there are hit in the TLB. Moreover this question is of $2$ marks. So its correctness can change the life of many students.

Your suggestion matters. Whole India is looking for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would a page being dirty lead to a fault? Doesn’t being marked dirty  simply mean it’s been written to and will require paging on eviction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398811/can-a-tlb-hit-lead-to-page-fault-in-memory
see the second answer

Comment: I’d ask the author of that answer the same question. In general I expect a TLB entry to contain permissions and a physical page, and, if permissions are given, the memory subsystem immediately goes to the physical page without further checking. If the physical page is out of range I’d expect a kernel panic...

Comment: But what about the question as a whole? Can there be page fault if TLB hit occurs?

Comment: Yes, your second example of a permissions error, which generally leads to program termination unless it’s a copy on write or similar scenario.

Comment: So what should be the ans of that question? 725 should be correct right?

Comment: The question could be edited to remove the Indian references. (Funnily enough, I myself searched for this question for similar doubts about questions in the Iranian admission exams.) They are irrelevant to the question, and give it a bad connotation. (It reads like Xianxia exaggeration.)